# Is it possible to use template litterals inside template litterals with javascript and yaml?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, yaml

I am making a bot in discord.js and I'm using YAML to create my config file. The bot creates an embed when the 'guildMemberAdd' event is fired. The config file includes configs about the content of the embed. I use placeholders for things relating to the user joining, the inviter and the time. These are in the form `${member.user.tag}`, `${invite.inviter.id}`, `${joinTime}`, etc. The config.yml for the embed and placeholders is as follows:

```yaml
# Avaliable placeholders:

# Joining User Placeholders:
#  ${member.user.id}
#  ${member.user.tag}
#  ${member.user.discriminator}
#  ${member.user.username}

# Inviter Placeholders:
#  ${invite.inviter.id}
#  ${invite.inviter.tag}
#  ${invite.inviter.discriminator}
#  ${invite.inviter.username}

# Miscellaneous
#  ${joinTime}

# Content on line 1 of embed
line1: "・<@${member.user.id}>\n"
# Content on line 2 of embed
line2: "・Account created <t:${joinTime}:R>\n"
# Content on line 3 of embed
line3: "・Invited by <@${invite.inviter.username}>"
```

The userJoin.js (the file which executes the code when a user joins a guild) is as follows:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { welcomeChannel } = require('../config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

const raw = fs.readFileSync('config.yml', 'utf8');
const data = yaml.load(raw);

module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    execute(client) {
        client.on('inviteCreate', (invite) => {
            client.invites[invite.code] = invite.uses
        })

        client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
            member.guild.invites.fetch().then(guildInvites => {
                guildInvites.each(invite => {
                    if (invite.uses != client.invites[invite.code]) {
                        var joinTime = Math.round(member.user.createdTimestamp / 1000);
                        console.log(line1)
                        const welcomeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setColor(data.embed_colour)
                            .setThumbnail(`${member.user.displayAvatarURL()}`)
                            .addFields(
                                { name: data.emoji + '' + data.title, value: `${data.line1}` },
                            )
                        client.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannel).send({ embeds: [welcomeEmbed] });
                        client.invites[invite.code] = invite.uses
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The specific error occurs at the .addFields section where I use a template litteral to reference the config section in the config.yaml for line1

```js
.addFields(
    { name: data.emoji + '' + data.title, value: `${data.line1}` },
)
```

[Output in discord](https://i.dumplings.dev/images/8mRGe.png)

[What I want it to be](https://i.dumplings.dev/images/asPLx.png)

To be clear the second image is from before when I hard-coded the lines, ie:

```
{ name: `<:welcome:1027459248856252436> User Joined`, value: `・<@${member.user.id}>\n` },
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can template strings be nested? Sure:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
console.log(`${obj.a} ${ true && `${obj.b}` }`); // 1 2
```

Can you pass a random string into template string and expect JS will parse that string as a template also? No.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const nestedTemplate = "${obj.b}";
console.log(`${obj.a} ${nestedTemplate}`); // 1 ${obj.b}
```

Template strings are parsed at "parse phase", you need some template engine which will be parse/substitute random strings at runtime. Starting from [messageformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messageformat) to [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

You will need to replace parameters once and use a result string as a template to replace parameters again.

Example:

```
import MessageFormat from '@messageformat/core';

const mf = new MessageFormat('en');

console.log(
  mf.compile(
    mf.compile("{templateFromVariable}")({ templateFromVariable: "{a}/{b}" })
  )({ a: 1, b: 9 })
);
```

Comment: How would I for example use [messageformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messageformat) to change the output of 
`console.log(`${obj.a} ${nestedTemplate}`);`
from ` // 1 ${obj.b}` to `// 1 2`?

Comment: added example to the answer